# Node.js - Stop application when port is undefined when using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If the users hasn't created a .env file with PORT=80 for example, then the port will be undefined.

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
    if (!process.env.PORT) {
        // stop the application
    } else {
        console.log(`\nTest is listening on port: ${process.env.PORT}.\n`);
    }    
});
```

I want to stop the application when the port is undefined, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. I've tried researching but can't find any information about this however I'm sure someone has tried or done it before.

Is it even a good idea to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`process.exit(code)`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) can be used to terminate `NodeJS` applications.

See below for a practical example.

```
if (!process.env.PORT) return process.exit(1) // Numbers other than 0 indicate that the process exited unusually
console.log('Port exists ..')
```